# Database type and engine for medium scale user content website

Tags: mysql, database

Using MySQL for basic storage of system/user data. I need to store/search messages (adding webmail functionality), and have analytic (on the fly reports/graphs from current and historical data, so kind of a data wearhouse) + this means i need to store historical data.

So the question is:
1) Do I use MySQL for everything or use separate databases for messages, analytics/historical data/user data? There is also live feeds on the site which I heard MySQL isn't very good with.

2) For tables that use MySQL is InnoDB good enough or do i need more advanced engines like TukoDB?

For messaging a friend mentioned to use a non relational database instead of MySQL. But if i use separate datbase types then that adds int he headache of keeping them all in sync and given this is a 24-7 user content site, I cant have any downtime.

--
Website is a high traffic user content website, lots of reads/writes but no money so I need to depend less on servers/hardware and more on the database/software to keep me afloat, hence open to only free/open source databases and database engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering the question directly I should say that your **concerns are premature**. A lot of **assumptions will be wrong** before you have a working project. So instead of designing perfect architecture, just make the project (non-perfect) and **be ready for the changes**.

Now, back to the question.

> For messaging a friend mentioned to
>   use a non relational database instead
>   of MySQL. But if i use separate
>   datbase types then that adds int he
>   headache of keeping them all in sync
>   and given this is a 24-7 user content
>   site, I cant have any downtime.

That was a good recommendation. You don't need to keep them in sync because you will persist different data in different databases.

- SQL database - for transactional data.
- Document Database - for historical and non structured.

> Website is a high traffic user content
>   website, **lots of reads/writes** but **no money** so I need to depend less on
>   servers/hardware and more on the database/software to keep me afloat,
>   hence open to only free/open source
>   databases and database engines.

If we will look at the [CAP](http://www.julianbrowne.com/article/viewer/brewers-cap-theorem) theorem and your requirements, we can tell that SQL database is not suitable for you because you sacrifice Partition tolerance or Availability for the sake of Consistency (which you don't seem to need).

From what you have described, you'll be better off with the database supporting Eventual Consistency. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is one of the most popular document databases.

I heard good things about [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/). It allows you to tune between Consistency, Availability and Partition Tolerance.

[Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) can be used for extremely high loads providing Consistency and Availability.

So I would recommend to:

- Use SQL database (InnoDB is good enough) for the critical data that requires high consistency.
- Use Document Database for higher traffic data (MongoDB, CoachDB).
- Use key/value (hash) Database for extremely hight traffic data (~Redis).
- Use the database you are the most comfortable with for the rest.

Comment: But I dont get this, you say I don't need to keep them in sync, but they still need to connect because let's take Mail. It links to a user which is in user table in MySQL DB. There will be user tags in the email which are in the tags table in MySQL. There will be user photos from profile photo album which are in MySQL db. The analytical info can go into the document DB but still needs to reference to the user in both DB. So at some level the 3 need to still relate?

Comment: The application can easily link all of those. The point is that you do not manually sync them. The application does it in real-time.

Comment: So live feeds would be best under a key/value DB while mail will be best under a document database and basic user profile details would be best under SQL?

Comment: @Tony38 generally yes, but I believe that most of the databases will handle pretty high load, so I personally would prefer to use a single DB. But just because of your requirements (which sound a bit unrealistic if it's not a Facebook/Google) you will better use different ones for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

What we do, in my company is this: we make a backup of our data every day, and compute statistical data from this backup. It's perfect for marketing purpose, for example. And so, we can stick to InnoDB...

For the moment, you don't need to think (too much) about what will happen when you will have 10 million users. Priority for you is to get something up and running!
So MySQL with InnoDB will do just fine.

When the first users will arrive, you will see what you need to improve...

Comment: But this is a social network. People need it to be real time. If a user posts an update and views his analytics it needs to be updated. At the most i can delay it for 2-3 minutes for not longer.

Comment: Maybe you should separate concerns about keeping users up to date and analytics? My company's business is a photo sharing web application with some social features. We just reached the million users and something like 40  million pictures. Data is currently stored on replicated MySQL servers running InnoDB, and it works fine. I'm experimenting with Apache Cassandra and MongoDB, but these are for a not so near future...

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html

if you read the first paragraph you'll see this:

"InnoDB is a high-reliability and high-performance storage engine for MySQL. **Starting with MySQL 5.5, it is the default MySQL storage engine. Key advantages of InnoDB include...**"

do i need to say more ?