# How can I store my atom data so my IRC bot can access it? Should I use SQL at all?

Tags: python, sql, nosql, rss, atom-feed

I want to add feeds such as ajaxian, smashingmagazine and store feeds starting today on my server, in order so that I can push the new items to my irc bot so it can echo them in my channel.

I will get ATOM data from this service: http://superfeedr.com/subscriber .. so I'm wondering which of the NoSQL storage mechanisms is ideal for storing ATOM data?

The atom data is xml, so they are documents, so perhaps something like CouchDB is suitable? Or MongoDb/Cassandra/Redis?

I'm aware that there are different kinds of no sql databases such as document oriented vs key/store, but as I don't have much experience I'd appreciate some insight from someone way more experienced. Thanks.

Additional things to consider

1. These won't be displayed on a website, or any publically viewable URL.
2. The only way to view them is to either a) wait for the bot to post new ones every hour or b) manually query the bot and give a time range or something like `0,20` and `20,40` through PM on IRC.
3. I won't really need to scale, I just have 15-20 people in the IRC chat room and only 1-3 people on average would probably query the bot at a given hour.
4. The bot will spit out new links every hour. The bot will never spit out old links.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you will have to use the database you are most comfortable with.

Also look at the CAP Theorem to clarify better what exactly you need.

Couple of minutes ago I [replied to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189464/database-type-and-engine-for-medium-scale-user-content-website/4189640#4189640). So you can have a look.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to read it but it's a lot to take in. I'm going to update my q with things to consider.

Comment: Then you just have to choose whatever you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

I want to store external rss feed data - is this a good reason to use NoSQL?

No

Comment: Can you elaborate on the technicalities of why I shouldn't?

Comment: I believe dportas did not mean that you *should not*, but rather that there is not enough reasoning to abandon SQL database (where you can store that data).

Answer (score 0):

If the content you're storing is natively XML, and you have need to be able to run queries against it (say, using XPath), you might consider a native XML database such as [eXist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/).

That said, it sounds like your needs are basic enough that any halfway-reasonable datastore will do.